# Permanent attribute join (for dissolving)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-joins, dissolve

I am quite new with QGIS and I have run into a problem that I would love your suggestions to. Here we go:

**I want to end up with a municipality map with the sum of perish population.**

Here's what I have:

> Layer1: (Shape) Parishes with municipality code and perish code as
>   attributes
>
> Layer2: (Attribute) population number with perish code as attributes

I am joining the layers, no problems so far, but when I want to dissolve and sum up population through the "Dissolve with stats" plugin, I don't see my joined attributes. I only see the original attributes and when I open the .dbf file in excel, I still only have the originals.

I figure that the join is not a "permanent" join, but just a "relational" one. Is there a way to change this or is there another way around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just save the layer to a new output file. All columns get added to the outcome.

You could also copy the columns manually with the field calculator to new columns.

Comment: Thank you :) It works (even though my headings changed)

Comment: Thats probably because the Shape-format only allows 10 characters for the column headings, which is not the case for the temporary joined columns.

Comment: If you save it as a geopackage i.e. as `.gpkg` you have not 10-character limit for the column-names.